# Method questions - What changes the value and what doesn't? What's invalid?

Tags: c++, templates, methods, vector, constants

I have the homework question

What  does  v  contain  after  these  methods  and  why?  If  the  method  is  invalid,  explain  why.

```
template <typename T> void reset1(MathVector<T> v) {v[0] = 0;}
template <typename T> void reset2(MathVector<T> &v) {v[0] = 0;}
template <typename T> void reset3(const MathVector<T> &v) {v[0] = 0;}
```

My previous experience tells me that the first would leave the vector unchanged because it's not being passed by value but rather by copy, the second would be changed properly, and the third would be invalid because the parameter specifies const.

However I'm pretty sure that in c++ arrays are always passed by value because it doesn't automatically invoke a copy constructor or anything. I suspect it might also be true of vectors but I'm not really sure. So if this was the case, the first one would change the vector and the second one would be invalid because you're trying to operate on the vector's pointer which doesn't make sense? I'm not really sure here

Comment: "arrays are always passed by value" - they're not, but that's not relevant here since you're passing a class type.

Comment: Compile a set of test cases and find out. Experimentation is for more than two chicks at a kegger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename T> void reset1(MathVector<T> v) {v[0] = 0;}
```

This passes the vector **by value**, so any modification to the vector `v` would be local only, and the original vector would be unchanged once the function is complete.

```
template <typename T> void reset2(MathVector<T> &v) {v[0] = 0;}
```

This passes the vector **by reference**, so changing the first element would be actually modifying the original vector. Here the first element would have been changed to 0.

```
template <typename T> void reset3(const MathVector<T> &v) {v[0] = 0;}
```

Here the vector is also passed **by reference, but it is `const`**. That means you may not attempt to modify the vector, it should at least produce a compiler warning.